# Installing few packages removed shotwell

Tags: uninstall, shotwell

While trying to install these packages: elementry-desktop, xubuntu-desktop & synaptic my shotwell got removed. Why? Will there be any conflict if I try to install shotwell again? Please help, I really like shotwell.

This is what happened:

`xxx@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop && sudo apt-get install
xubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apport-hooks-elementary bamfdaemon bluez-gstreamer capnet-assist contractor
  dmz-cursor-theme doc-base elementary-artwork elementary-default-settings
  elementary-icon-theme elementary-os-prerelease elementary-theme
  elementary-wallpapers elementaryos-report-problem-dockitem
  fonts-capture-it-elementary fonts-daniel-elementary fonts-elementary-core
  fonts-elementary-extra fonts-hvd-bodedo-elementary
  fonts-jenna-sue-elementary fonts-khmer-mondulkiri-elementary
  fonts-limelight-elementary fonts-lobster-elementary
  fonts-open-sans-elementary fonts-operating-instructions-elementary
  fonts-plainblack-elementary fonts-raleway-elementary gcalctool geary
  geoclue-ubuntu-geoip ginn gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gnome-power-manager
  gnome-screensaver gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps
  gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps gstreamer1.0-tools
  gtk2-engines-murrine gtk3-engines-unico
  gtksourceview-3.0-theme-solarized-elementary indicator-bluetooth
  indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-power indicator-session
  indicator-sound language-selector-gnome libaccount-plugin-1.0-0
  libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-qt5-1
  libbamf3-2 libffmpegthumbnailer4 libgee2 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libopenraw1
  libopenrawgnome1 libplank-common libplank0 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5
  libqt5gui5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5positioning5
  libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5
  libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5
  libsignon-extension1 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1
  libswitchboard-2.0-0 libtimezonemap1 libtumbler-1-0 liburl-dispatcher1
  libuuid-perl libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-xkb1 libxkbcommon-x11-0
  libyaml-tiny-perl light-locker light-locker-settings lightdm notify-osd
  notify-osd-icons onboard onboard-data p7zip-full pantheon pantheon-print
  plank plank-theme-pantheon plymouth-theme-elementary
  plymouth-theme-elementary-text print-test-page-elementary
  pulseaudio-module-gconf python-psutil signon-keyring-extension
  signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui signond switchboard-plug-gcc-bluetooth
  switchboard-plug-gcc-color switchboard-plug-gcc-date
  switchboard-plug-gcc-display switchboard-plug-gcc-mouse
  switchboard-plug-gcc-network switchboard-plug-gcc-printer
  switchboard-plug-gcc-sound switchboard-plug-gcc-ua
  switchboard-plug-gcc-users switchboard-plug-gcc-wacom switchboard-plug-power
  tumbler tumbler-common tumbler-plugins-extra unity-control-center
  unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter unity-settings-daemon
  xcursor-themes
Suggested packages:
  rarian-compat notify-osd-icons-elementary murrine-themes click
  unity-greeter-session-broadcast url-dispatcher p7zip-rar
  lightdm-remote-session-freerdp lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure
  remote-login-service
Recommended packages:
  pantheon-terminal noise pantheon-greeter switchboard
  switchboard-gnome-control-center-override switchboard-plug-about
  switchboard-plug-applications switchboard-plug-keyboard
  switchboard-plug-locale switchboard-plug-online-accounts
  switchboard-plug-pantheon-shell switchboard-plug-security-privacy
  user-specific-alternatives indicator-applet indicator-renderer audience
  maya-calendar midori-granite pantheon-files pantheon-photos
  scratch-text-editor snap-photobooth
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  evolution-data-server-online-accounts shotwell shotwell-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apport-hooks-elementary bamfdaemon bluez-gstreamer capnet-assist contractor
  dmz-cursor-theme doc-base elementary-artwork elementary-default-settings
  elementary-desktop elementary-icon-theme elementary-os-prerelease
  elementary-theme elementary-wallpapers elementaryos-report-problem-dockitem
  fonts-capture-it-elementary fonts-daniel-elementary fonts-elementary-core
  fonts-elementary-extra fonts-hvd-bodedo-elementary
  fonts-jenna-sue-elementary fonts-khmer-mondulkiri-elementary
  fonts-limelight-elementary fonts-lobster-elementary
  fonts-open-sans-elementary fonts-operating-instructions-elementary
  fonts-plainblack-elementary fonts-raleway-elementary gcalctool geary
  geoclue-ubuntu-geoip ginn gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gnome-power-manager
  gnome-screensaver gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps
  gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps gstreamer1.0-tools
  gtk2-engines-murrine gtk3-engines-unico
  gtksourceview-3.0-theme-solarized-elementary indicator-bluetooth
  indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-power indicator-session
  indicator-sound language-selector-gnome libaccount-plugin-1.0-0
  libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-qt5-1
  libbamf3-2 libffmpegthumbnailer4 libgee2 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libopenraw1
  libopenrawgnome1 libplank-common libplank0 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5
  libqt5gui5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5positioning5
  libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5
  libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5
  libsignon-extension1 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1
  libswitchboard-2.0-0 libtimezonemap1 libtumbler-1-0 liburl-dispatcher1
  libuuid-perl libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-xkb1 libxkbcommon-x11-0
  libyaml-tiny-perl light-locker light-locker-settings lightdm notify-osd
  notify-osd-icons onboard onboard-data p7zip-full pantheon pantheon-print
  plank plank-theme-pantheon plymouth-theme-elementary
  plymouth-theme-elementary-text print-test-page-elementary
  pulseaudio-module-gconf python-psutil signon-keyring-extension
  signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui signond switchboard-plug-gcc-bluetooth
  switchboard-plug-gcc-color switchboard-plug-gcc-date
  switchboard-plug-gcc-display switchboard-plug-gcc-mouse
  switchboard-plug-gcc-network switchboard-plug-gcc-printer
  switchboard-plug-gcc-sound switchboard-plug-gcc-ua
  switchboard-plug-gcc-users switchboard-plug-gcc-wacom switchboard-plug-power
  tumbler tumbler-common tumbler-plugins-extra unity-control-center
  unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter unity-settings-daemon
  xcursor-themes
0 upgraded, 131 newly installed, 3 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 49.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 179 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`

---

**Additional Details**

1. Installation of synaptic package showed following error:

   `` Scrollkeeper was installed, forcing re-registration of all documents.
   Unregistering 68 doc-base files, re-registering 71 doc-base files...
   Error in /usr/share/doc-base/gstreamer-1.0-pwg', line 14: allFormat' sections are invalid.
   Error in /usr/share/doc-base/gstreamer-1.0-manual', line 11: allFormat' sections are invalid.
   Error in /usr/share/doc-base/gstreamer-1.0-faq', line 9: allFormat' sections are invalid.
   Note: `install-docs --verbose --check file_name' may give more details about the above errors.
   Registering documents with scrollkeeper... ``
2. ElementryOS is not there in the list in logon page.

Comment: Note: you can install more than one package at a time - e.g. `sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop xubuntu-desktop synaptic`. Does `sudo apt-get install shotwell shotwell-common` do anything?

Comment: Output:
http://i.imgur.com/zmnXaQB.jpg
I guess, that's safe to install?

Comment: Yes, Shotwell is safe to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command to reinstall those packages:

```
sudo apt-get install shotwell shotwell-common
```

Unless is says it will remove half the system, it should be fine to install it.

As for the elementary OS desktop, you may need to add one of the PPAs from [here](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os) *(stable versions are usually best if you want something that just works)* to install it, and then you need to select the Pantheon desktop environment from the login screen.

Comment: Can you suggest me any solution for that error occurred during synaptic installation?

Comment: Does synaptic work? I would suggest googling for an answer, and if that doesn't work, post a new question.

Comment: Well, it seem to work, but my system show me a lot of error messages frequently!

Comment: You can post a new question if you need to - bear in mind there is a difference between error messages and it just telling you stuff :-)